# Sencha Grid and Action Column

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.1

I have this on a grid:

```
{                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            renderer: function (val, metadata, record) {
                if (record.raw.possibleActions != 2) {
                    this.items[0].icon = '';
                    this.items[0].tooltip = '';
                }

                metadata.style = 'cursor: pointer;';
                return val;
            },
            width: 30,
            align: 'center',
            sortable: false,
            items: [{
                icon: 'images/edit.png',
                tooltip: 'stuff',
                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                    'do stuff'
                }
            }]
        },
```

I want that when the field "possibleActions" is different than 2 to hide icon of the action column.

With this `this.items[0].icon = '';` it removes the icon from all the columns...

How can i access the column for the specific row that matches the condition??

Answer (score 5):

I've solved it:

```
renderer: function (val, metadata, record) {
                if (record.raw.possibleActions != 2) {
                    this.items[0].icon = '';
                    this.items[0].tooltip = '';
                } else {
                    this.items[0].icon = 'images/edit.png';
                    this.items[0].tooltip = 'RELATÓRIO FINAL';
                }

                metadata.style = 'cursor: pointer;';
                return val;
            },
```

It seems that renderer overwrites the initial configuration and that was why all record had no icons.

Answer (score 1):

Well using `this` there is really risky. You may end up with some other instance.

But ok, if you have the instance I recommend you to use

```
setVisible(false);
disable();
```

to disable and

```
setVisible(true);
enable();
```

to enable. Simply removing the image will not be enough.

Comment: The problem is that either 'this' or 'grid.columns' refer to all the columns... I want to be able to access that specific one.

Comment: @MiguelTeixeira As I thought... well that will be hard. The problem is, that the renderer function (which can be 'overridden') knows about the value but not about the Column-type. For your case you need to mixup both. I guess the best way will be create your own action column. With that you have the full control so that you are abel the fire a listener that contains the value + the instance

Comment: Thanks for the help, i've figure it out.